# FilterRegistrationBeans not executing with introduction of springSecurityFilterChain

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot

If I set up SS HttpSecurity using Java Config. Spring Boot creates a springSecurityFilterChain, which is logged during setup logs.  However, the FilterRegistrationBeans now with standard URL patterns are not invoked.

## 2 Part Question:

1. Is this standard behavior?  Where... once Spring Security is installed, all of my Servlet FilterBeanRegistrations are suddenly broken??  I would have thought Spring Boot would auto-figure out how to "add" them onto the appropriate springSecurityFilterChain automatically.  Anyway, that is not what I am seeing.
2. I see the http.addFilter(myFilter) API methods.  But, I don't want to pollute my SecurityConfig to know about all these filters I have.  How do I add my custom Servlet filters into the springSecurityFilterChain bean from the 'outside' so to speak?  You know.. 'auto-configure' them myself, onto the springSecurityFilterChain. :)

Comment: FilterRegistratonBeans register Filter beans with the servlet container. They have nothing to do with Spring Security. How have you identified that they're broken? Why do you want them to be part of Spring Security's filter chain?

Comment: When I do "/*", my custom filters are called before the Spring Security FC.  I need them called after SS FC but before my service is invoked.  I have not seen them execute at all (in debugger or log files) when using specific url patterns - only "/*" seems to catch them.

Comment: You can use @Order on your Filters to ensure they run after Spring Security's Filter. The Spring Security Filter has a default order of zero, I think. Give your Filters a lower precedence (higher value).

Answer (score 0):

As you can see below, the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` adds a lot of stuff to the security filter chain by default.

Although I still don't know which one of the settings caused the `FilterBeanRegistrations` to break, setting `disableDefaults` to `true` and configuring the security filter chain myself did the trick.

```
    if(!disableDefaults) {
        http
            .csrf().and()
            .addFilter(new WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter())
            .exceptionHandling().and()
            .headers().and()
            .sessionManagement().and()
            .securityContext().and()
            .requestCache().and()
            .anonymous().and()
            .servletApi().and()
            .apply(new DefaultLoginPageConfigurer<HttpSecurity>()).and()
            .logout();
    }
```